# Is the highlighted part a noun phrase acting as an appositive or an absolute phrase, modifying the previous clause?

Tags: phrases, modifiers, appositives, absolute-constructions

> His chest and arms were thick and roped with muscle, ***testament to the athlete he’d once been***.

In the sentence above, is "***testament to ...***" modifying the previous clause "***his chest ..***"?

Also, is "***testament to the ...*** "(noun phrase since it doesn't have a main verb) an appositive or an absolute phrase? (there's no article before *testament*)

> I had added my indelible mark to Laconia Avenue, ***a testament to the world that Wes Moore lived—or at least Kid Kupid did***.

Here, the highlighted section has an article. Is it an appositive or an absolute phrase modifying the previous clause?

Similarly,
***Court ordered to ..., a decision that ...***

What is "***a decision that ...***" called?

Comment: More common than an anarthrous _testament_ in this construction is _a testament_. I'd view either NP as an appositive to the entire clause preceding it, or as a Whiz-deleted relative clause with predicate noun phrase.