# "a statement, a noun related to the statement" is a weird case of apposition?

Tags: grammar, phrases, appositives

> Joanna does a lot of charity work, a discussion she’s had plenty of times with a client.

The clause after the comma looks like it could be an [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) but an apposition should follow a noun phrase to be in apposition to. This is not the case.

Is the sentence logically and grammatically correct? If so is this grammatical construct described somewhere?

I encountered the sentence in internal company training slides.

Comment: This resembles [an earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/590709/is-the-highlighted-part-a-noun-phrase-acting-as-an-appositive-or-an-absolute-phr) which was unanswered, but see John Lawler's comment.

Comment: One of the most common uses of apposition, especially repeated appositions, is simply repetition of the first phrase in slightly different, lengthier, or clearer form.

Comment: This also happens with cascades of titles, e.g, _His Royal Highness The Prince Charles Philip Arthur George, Prince of Wales, Duke of Cornwall, Duke of Rothesay, Duke of Edinburgh, Earl of Chester, Earl of Carrick, Earl of Merioneth, Baron of Renfrew, Baron Greenwich, Lord of the Isles, Prince and Great Steward of Scotland, KG, KT, GCB, OM, AK, QSO, CC, CMM, PC, ADC._

Comment: Apart from the whole thing not making much sense, it doesn't qualify as apposition because the supplement ( "a discussion she’s had plenty of times with a client") cannot be substituted for the whole construction in such a way as to yield an entailment of the original. *"Joanna does a discussion she’s had plenty of times with a client" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: There seems to be a dangling reference in this. A discussion isn't charity work. I guess they're trying to say that she's discussed her charity work with the client.